# How to execute a tap with given coordinates in Android

Tags: java, android

I need to have an automatic tap executed onscreen with given coordinates without any user input.

So when i call this function with given coordinates that i already found out via developer tools, then it should simulate the user clicking the screen right there.

this is the code:

```
public void simulateClick(float x, float y) {
        long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        MotionEvent.PointerProperties[] properties = new MotionEvent.PointerProperties[1];
        MotionEvent.PointerProperties pp1 = new MotionEvent.PointerProperties();
        pp1.id = 0;
        pp1.toolType = MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_FINGER;
        properties[0] = pp1;
        MotionEvent.PointerCoords[] pointerCoords = new MotionEvent.PointerCoords[1];
        MotionEvent.PointerCoords pc1 = new MotionEvent.PointerCoords();
        pc1.x = x;
        pc1.y = y;
        pc1.pressure = 1;
        pc1.size = 1;
        pointerCoords[0] = pc1;
        MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 1, properties,
                pointerCoords, 0,  0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
        dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);

        motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 1, properties,
                pointerCoords, 0,  0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
        dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }
```

Yet it doesnt work or do anything, its not giving me errors, its just not doing anything...

Comment: Are you tapping on your app or another app?  If its another app, nothing will work-  this is prevented by the framework for security.  To do it in another app you need root and to send tap data via the Linux input subsystem.  For your app-  there's probably better/easier ways of doing whatever you actually want.

Comment: I want to execute a tap to another app, just in general on the view. My phone has root, thats not the problem, linux input subsystem... sounds interesting, i found some adb shell commands, yet my adb server is outdated for some reason, so that doesnt give me any room to build stuff... i just need to execute a simple tap anywhere on the screen, like for example executeTap(200, 300) then it will execute a single tap on coordinates x 200 and y 300